# Select row belonging to multiple categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 2 tables.  The first table is full of entries.  The second table defines what categories that entry belongs to:

Table 1:

```
entry_id | title
       1 | Entry1
       2 | Entry2
       3 | Entry3
```

Table 2

```
entry_id | cat_id
       1 | 233
       1 | 234
       1 | 678
       2 | 235
       2 | 453
       2 | 21
       3 | 234
       3 | 233
```

I'm trying to select an entry with a single query of all posts belonging to multiple categories.  For example, I want to return the entries belonging to category ids, 233 and 234.  I believe this needs a subquery although I'm not quite sure.  Any help anybody? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified this.  The returned entries need to belong to ALL categories.  It should be the intersection, not the union

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from entity e
where exists (select * from category c where c.entry_id=e.entry_id AND c.cat_id=233)
  and exists (select * from category c where c.entry_id=e.entry_id AND c.cat_id=234)
```

This returns rows that belong to *both* 233 and 234 (this is how I read your question, anyway; I may have misunderstood the "belonging to multiple categories" part).

Answer (score 9):

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 USING (entry_id) WHERE cat_id IN (233,234);
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55073/1/0).

---

**UPDATE**

To select all entries in *both* categories, you could group the results of the join and only select those groups that have contain both categories:

```
SELECT   tbl1.*
FROM     tbl1 JOIN tbl2 USING (entry_id)
WHERE    cat_id IN (233,234)
GROUP BY entry_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT cat_id) = 2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55073/5/0).

The `COUNT(DISTINCT cat_id)` can obviously be replaced with the (much less expensive) `COUNT(*)` if `(entry_id, cat_id)` is known to be unique in `tbl2`.

Comment: wow i was way over-complicating that in my head.  it wasn't the join but the IN for some reason that I was having a brain-fart about.

Comment: ok, actually, I think this does not actually solve the problem I was having.  I need this to be function as an AND

Comment: @Macgyver: In that case, [@dasblinkenlight's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11264317/623041) is one way of doing what you want.  There is another, with which I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: got it, thanks for your help.  yours is right as well, but his is a little more useful in the context of my program as it is easier to loop through and generate dynamically based on categories selected,  so I'm marking his as correct.

Comment: @Macgyver: No problem.  Just beware that the performance of his will degrade linearly with each additional category, whereas mine should give constant performance.  Building mine dynamically ought not to be too difficult either (just implode the categories into the `IN` expression and then give the count of the number of categories to the `HAVING` clause) -- e.g. in PHP: `$sql="... cat_id IN (".implode(',',$categories).") ... HAVING COUNT(...) =".count($categories);`