# MySQL query that uses HAVING is limiting results incorrectly

Tags: mysql

I have an advanced search form that offers a bunch of ways to filter your search. Here's a simplified idea (doesn't include keyword text input or date range searches or other select menus):

```
Topic: 
<select><option>any</option><option>all</option></select>
[] Aging
[] Environment
[] Health
[] Hunger
[] Poverty

Document type: 
<select><option>any</option><option>all</option></select>
[] Case Study
[] Policy Brief
[] Whitepaper
```

If someone selects "any" when they choose more than one topic or document type, the query needs to include, eg., topic = "Aging" **OR** topic = "Health".

If someone selects "all" when they choose more than one topic or document type, the query needs to include, eg., topic = "Aging" **AND** topic = "Health".

We default to "AND" between these different filters. So when you search for all documents categorized under Aging and all documents categorized as a whitepaper, the query is: topic = "Aging" **AND** doctype = "whitepaper".

**The Problem:** We have a query that is working when the search is for "any". But when the search is for "all", according to MySQL's "EXPLAIN" command, we have an "impossible WHERE". :(

**Here is the query that works** when someone selects "any" for both topic and document type:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT * 
FROM research 
JOIN link_resource_doctype ON link_resource_doctype.resource_id = research.research_id 
JOIN doctype ON doctype.id = link_resource_doctype.doctype_id 
JOIN link_resource_issue_area ON link_resource_issue_area.resource_id = research.research_id 
JOIN issue_area ON issue_area.id = link_resource_issue_area.issue_area_id 
WHERE approved = '1' 
AND (doctype.identifier = 'case_study' OR doctype.identifier = 'whitepaper') 
AND (issue_area.identifier = 'aging' OR issue_area.identifier = 'health')
```

And **here's the same query which does not work** when someone selects "all" for both topic and document type (this also doesn't work if someone selects just topic or just document type):

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT * 
FROM research 
JOIN link_resource_doctype ON link_resource_doctype.resource_id = research.research_id 
JOIN doctype ON doctype.id = link_resource_doctype.doctype_id 
JOIN link_resource_issue_area ON link_resource_issue_area.resource_id = research.research_id 
JOIN issue_area ON issue_area.id = link_resource_issue_area.issue_area_id 
WHERE approved = '1' 
AND (doctype.identifier = 'case_study' AND doctype.identifier = 'whitepaper') 
AND (issue_area.identifier = 'aging' AND issue_area.identifier = 'health')
```

**Possible solution but there's a problem:** I came across this post on Stackoverflow -- [Select row belonging to multiple categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264264/select-row-belonging-to-multiple-categories) -- which contains a query that I think might solve our problem when someone selects "all". Here it is:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT * 
FROM research 
JOIN link_issue_area ON link_issue_area.resource_id = research.research_id 
JOIN link_doctype ON link_doctype.resource_id = research.research_id 
WHERE issue_area.identifier IN ('aging', 'health')
AND 
doctype_id.identifier IN ('case_study', 'whitepaper')
GROUP BY research.research_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT issue_area.identifier) = 2 
AND 
COUNT(DISTINCT doctype.identifier) = 2
```

**The Problem:** This query does seem to work for either "any" or "all", except for one problem. Say that a document is categorized under Aging, Health, and Poverty but the person searching only checked off Aging and Health. The document that is categorized under the two topics that are checked off and also Poverty, which wasn't checked, will not appear in the search result list. I think this is because of the HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT issue_area.identifier) = 2 -- the 2 excludes any document that actually has a COUNT that is more than 2. Is there a work-around for this? Or a better query to use here?

Any insight, ideas, assistance much appreciated! Thanks!

Here's an SQLfiddle that gets at all of this too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/847362/1

Comment: Are you generating your queries dynamically? If not, you need to consider parameterising them - the logic of an "any" select is obviously going to be different to an "all" select; a single, static, unparameterised query can only select according to the specific criteria in the query. Also, if you want to see all issue areas and doctypes for a given research_id, you should use `group_concat` when grouping; grouping by research_id means that only a single row will be returned for each research_id, while not using aggregate functions means that the record rows returned will essentially be random.

Comment: @user1286755, please see [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/847362/14). Is this the one you want to achieve?

Comment: @Mark Bannister - thanks for your response. Yes - the query is generated dynamically. What I need to get out of this query is a distinct list of records that are categorized X and Y (or, 'X or Y', or both). I do not need to get all issue areas or doctypes that are attached to a record or records.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question because you don't show the expected output. But from what I understand, this is *what I have done so far*. Please comment what is the error:

**Possible solution but might work:**

```
SELECT   research.research_id AS resource_id, research.title
FROM     research
JOIN     link_issue_area ON link_issue_area.resource_id = research.research_id
JOIN     link_doctype ON link_doctype.resource_id = research.research_id
JOIN (SELECT resource_id, COUNT(DISTINCT issue_area_id) AS ISSUE_COUNT FROM link_issue_area
      GROUP BY resource_id) TB1_COUNT ON TB1_COUNT.resource_id = research.research_id
JOIN (SELECT resource_id, COUNT(DISTINCT doctype_id) AS DOCTYPE_COUNT FROM link_doctype
     GROUP BY resource_id) TB2_COUNT ON TB2_COUNT.resource_id = research.research_id
WHERE    issue_area_id IN (5,10)
AND       doctype_id IN (3,18)
AND   TB1_COUNT.ISSUE_COUNT = 2
AND TB2_COUNT.DOCTYPE_COUNT = 2
GROUP BY resource_id
LIMIT 0,1
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/847362/14)

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem is: in a search for all records categorized under X and Y, only records categorized with *exactly* X and Y appear in the results. However, a record that is categorized under X and Y and Z should also appear in the results because that record meets the criteria of being categorized under X and Y. I think this: "HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category) = 2", returns records categorized with 2 and *only* 2 categories. If a record has 3 categories, even if 2 of the categories are the ones requested, it will not be included in the result set.

Comment: I am trying to give you a dbase schema, and then some question/answers but it's not working so well in this comment box formatting-wise. let me post something online and give you a link.

Comment: ok - I've posted tables with data and possible queries here: http://ilaborate.org/problem_query.html. Appreciate your help Christian Mark!

Answer (score 0):

The existing query from your SQLFiddle is pretty much all you need, as long as you only include the HAVING conditions dynamically where all of the options are required. Like so:

```
SELECT   research.research_id AS resource_id, research.title 
FROM     research 
JOIN     link_issue_area ON link_issue_area.resource_id = research.research_id 
JOIN     link_doctype ON link_doctype.resource_id = research.research_id 
WHERE    issue_area_id IN (5,10) /* dynamically-generated list of issues */
  AND    doctype_id IN (3,18) /* dynamically-generated list of doc types */
GROUP BY resource_id
HAVING 1=1
  AND    COUNT(DISTINCT issue_area_id) = 2 /* dynamically-generated count of
      user-selected issues - only included when all specified issues required */
  AND    COUNT(DISTINCT doctype_id) = 2 /* dynamically-generated count of
      user-selected doc types - only included when all specified types required*/
```

Including the dummy condition `1=1` means that you can always include a HAVING clause, even if none of the options are `all`.

So your dynamically-generated query to return resources that have all issues 5 and 10, and all document types 3 and 18 would look like:

```
SELECT   research.research_id AS resource_id, research.title 
FROM     research 
JOIN     link_issue_area ON link_issue_area.resource_id = research.research_id 
JOIN     link_doctype ON link_doctype.resource_id = research.research_id 
WHERE    issue_area_id IN (5,10)
  AND    doctype_id IN (3,18)
GROUP BY resource_id
HAVING 1=1
  AND    COUNT(DISTINCT issue_area_id) = 2
  AND    COUNT(DISTINCT doctype_id) = 2
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/847362/27).

While a dynamically-generated query to return resources that have any of issues 10 and 20, and any of document types 15 and 18 would look like:

```
SELECT   research.research_id AS resource_id, research.title 
FROM     research 
JOIN     link_issue_area ON link_issue_area.resource_id = research.research_id 
JOIN     link_doctype ON link_doctype.resource_id = research.research_id 
WHERE    issue_area_id IN (10,20)
  AND    doctype_id IN (15,18)
GROUP BY resource_id
HAVING 1=1
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/847362/28).